# How to put what the user picks for the row and column in the board

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So my question is how do I put what the user enters, for example, they put row : 1 and column: 2 in my board that I made. I'm working on this in the `void playerChoice` function.

I've thought of some solutions to this problem like board[row][column] = 'X' in like an if statement with board[row][column] = 'O' as well. Is this alright?

Hopefully you guys can help figure this problem this out with me.

```
const int ROWS = 3; // For the rows 
const int COLS = 3; // For the number of columns;
void showBoard(const char[][COLS], int); // Shows the board 
void playerChoice(char[][COLS], char); // shows the player choice 
int winner(const char[][COLS],
  const char, string);

int main() {
  char board[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {
      '*',
      '*',
      '*'
    },
    {
      '*',
      '*',
      '*'
    },
    {
      '*',
      '*',
      '*'
    }
  };
  string winner = " ";
  showBoard(board, 3); // displays the board

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    playerChoice(board, 'X');
    showBoard(board, 3);

    playerChoice(board, 'O');
    showBoard(board, 3);
  }

  cout << "The winner is:" << winner;
}

void showBoard(const char arr[][COLS], int SIZE) {
  for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
      cout << '|' << arr[row][col];
    cout << '|' << endl;
  }
}

void playerChoice(char arr[][COLS], char name) {
  int row, columns;

  cout << "What row would you like?\n";
  cout << "Row: ";
  cin >> row;

  while (row < 1 || row > 3) {
    cout << "Error please pick a row in between 1 and 3.\n";
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << endl;

  }

  cout << "What column would you like?\n";
  cout << "Column: ";
  cin >> columns;

  while (columns < 1 || columns > 3) {
    cout << "Error,please pick a row in between 1 and 3.\n";
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> columns;
    cout << endl;
  }

}
int winner(const char[][COLS],
  const char, string) {

  // working on this.

  return winner;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've thought of some solutions to this problem like board[row][column]
> = 'X' in like an if statement with board[row][column] = 'O' as well.

Yes. You can try the code below:

```
if (arr[row - 1][columns - 1] == '*')
{
    arr[row - 1][columns - 1] = name;
}
else
{
    cout << "Retry" << endl;
    playerChoice(arr, name);
}
```

Comment: @MARRSVISTER
: Hi,  does this solve your problem? If so, please help to mark  answer.

Comment: Yu:  What does the [row - 1] and the others mean?

Comment: Arr[0][] is the first row. Arr[1][] is the second row. So arr[row-1][] is the row you want.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
unsigned int row = 0u;
unsigned int column = 0u;
char board[3][3] = {' '};

std::cout << "Enter row: ";
std::cin >> row;
std::cout << "Enter column: ";
std::cin >> column;

// Insert a character at the User's row and column
board[row][column] = 'X';
```

If you want to insert the User's coordinates into the board, you'll need a different type of board.

**Edit 1:  A different type of board**
Let's call the items of the board a Cell.
In order to store the row and column, you'll need a cell that can store the row and column:

```
struct Cell
{
  char c;
  unsigned int row;
  unsigned int column;
};

Cell board[3][3];
//...
board[row][column].c = 'O';
board[row][column].row = row;
board[row][column].column = column;
```

Comment: Hmm when you say I need a different board, do you mean like board[0][1] in the showBoard function? I would like to keep it the way it is right now. Thanks though. I don't think it will work for me.

Comment: Your board only stores a character in each cell.  In order to store the row and column into a cell, you'll need to create a struct that contains a character and the row and column.  See my **Edit 1**.

Comment: I don't understand why you are storing the row and column in a board cell.

Comment: I'm new to c++ and coding in general so I thought its good, but I'll consider your help. Thank you. @Thomas Matthews